# Changing Query Criteria doesnt change query results viewed on form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a simple database I am developing in MS Access 2010 where I have a form with a "view specific" command button and a "view all" command button.  Both buttons will run a query: the specific one should apply a criteria to one of the fields, and the all one should run the query with no criteria, or with a * criteria in that field.  There is another field that requires criteria for both queries, so essentially the specific button should run a query with two criteria and the all button should run a query with one criteria (or one and an * criteria).  The query is a stored query I created via Design View.  The "all" SQL statement is something to the effect of:

```
SELECT tableA.field1, tableA.field2, tableB.field1, tableB.field2
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.field3=tableB.field2
WHERE tableB.field1=True;
```

I want the specific query to run based off of an option chosen in a combo box on the form, so it's SQL statement should look the same, except the WHERE clause would change to:

```
WHERE tableB.field1=True AND tableB.field2=Forms!ViewQryResults!comboSelectSpecific;
```

**Problem**

My problem is that the specific query, I'll call it *Query2*, works as intended, but the all query, *Query1*, doesn't change the results viewed on the form.  Neither query throws an error message, and it seems that the query is running again as the record total at the bottom of the screen goes away, and then comes back after the query finishes and gets a total number of records again.

**Attempted Solutions**

I have tried multiple different solutions to attempt to get it to work, none of which have.

1. I first tried to establish a parameter, but then Access prompts the user for the parameter value as soon as the form opens, which I do not want.  If I simply declare the parameter using the parameter button in the ribbon in design view for the query, but do not assign it to a field as a criterion in the design grid, Access no longer prompts me for the parameter value, and I can assign its value via VBA, but then I do not know how to assign the parameter to a field criteria using VBA.  My attempts throw errors that say Access doesn't recognize the name of my parameter.
2. I then tried altering the SQL string for the query and then requerying.  I used text manipulation functions to find the WHERE clause, and replace it with a WHERE clause that has both criteria, then requeryed.  To determine the proper context for the SQL string, I changed the query in Design View to do what I wanted, and then switched to SQL View and copied the SQL string that Access created to represent the query.

   I then inserted a `Debug.Print` line to print the SQL string at each step, and compared them character by character and they match exactly, meaning the text manipulation is doing what it should be doing and creating the SQL strings correctly, or at least as Access would if I wasn't messing with them at all.  I tried this from both directions, i.e. I made the stored query in the way it should be for one button, and then used code to change it for the other button, and then swapped, but neither method was successful in getting both queries to work.  The basic code I tried for manipulating the SQL string is as follows:

   ```vb
   Private Sub Query2_OnClick()
       Dim d As Database
       Dim q As Query
       Dim strSQL As String
       Dim strSQLSelectFrom As String
       Dim strSQLWhereNew As String

       Set d = CurrentDb
       Set q = d.QueryDefs("Query2")
       strSQL = q.SQL      'Saves original SQL statement
       'Text Manipulations to create strSQLSelectFrom as just the SELECT and FROM portions
       strSQLWhereNew = "tableB.field1=True AND tableB.field2=Forms!ViewQryResults!comboSelectSpecific;"

       q.SQL = strSQLSelectFrom & strSQLWhereNew
       DoCmd.Requery
       Me.Refresh
       Debug.Print q.SQL   'Verify text manipulations created SQL String I expect
       q.SQL = strSQL      'Returns SQL to original statement
       Debug.Print q.SQL   'Verify SQL statement properly returned to original statement
   End Sub
   ```

This arrangement works to allow me to query specifics based on my combo box.  When I click the other button, whose code just does a requery because the first button should reset SQL to the way it was, the results do not change.  The query appears to run as indicated by the total records counter going away and coming back, but it never changes the results.  If I go back and choose another option from my combo box, and query specific, the results update to the new specific selection.

Again, if I click the All Query button, the results remain based on the combo box selection.  If I change the combo box selection, and then click All Query (which shouldn't care at all about the combo box because it isn't listed anywhere in the code for that button), the results change to the new selection, like both buttons are running specific queries.  That part is the most puzzling, I can figure out why it is doing that.

I know a simple solution would be just to create a second query and stop trying to change one back and forth, but I really feel I am missing a fundamental piece that I am going to need to understand at some point, so I am really looking for that fundamental piece that will make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC - Simply change the form's [RecordSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-recordsource-property-access) to point to needed saved query with `.Requery`:

```vb
Private Sub ViewAll_OnClick()
   Me.Form.RecordSource = "Query1"
   Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub ViewSpecific_OnClick()
   Me.Form.RecordSource = "Query2"
   Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can keep the same query recordsource and filter form using [DoCmd.ApplyFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-applyfilter-method-access), assuming criteria controls are on same form requiring filtering. Any valid SQL `WHERE` clause can be used in second argument and even dynamically created.

```vb
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "field1 = True AND field2 = '" & Forms!ViewQryResults!comboSelectSpecific & "'"
```

And to remove filter:

```vb
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRemoveAllFilters
```

Comment: While I understand I can create a second query and use this solution, I am trying to understand the fundamentals behind more dynamic queries.  In this case, I only need two versions of the query, so it wouldn't be problematic to do this,  but I may come upon a situation that requires 50 queries, and this solution would require me to create a query for each situation, which I do not want to have to do...  Is there a way I can leave the forms recordsource property pointing to one query, and change the query to meet the needs accordingly using VBA?

Comment: I got some databases were users needed more than 100 queries, all the same style but criterias for users changes, and filters too. What i did is just to have a `String variable` where to declare the SQL instructions, and then I do what @Parfait suugested you. I set the `Form.RecordSource=MySQL` where `MySQL` is my string variable, and then `Me. Requery` will update. So my form is always pointing to 1 query, and then I change the record source using VBA and SQL language

Comment: @Valiant ... IIUC you can use `DoCmd.ApplyFilter`. See edit above and pass the SQL `WHERE` condition as second argument. This condition can even be dynamically created as a VBA string.

Comment: Thank you!  The filter option worked for this situation, and between asking and commenting now I have learned how to create the SQL strings from VBA, so I can now dynamically create my queries and assign them as recordsource using your first option!  I have already had to do this for another unrelated problem I had!